# Redirect Multiple URL within folder to other domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have some files placed under a particular folder in my old domain:

```
http://www.olddmain.com/subfolder/example1.html
```

I want to redirect all files under this folder to a new domain. 
Example:

```
http://www.newdomain.com/subfolder/example1.html
```

How do I do this without losing Ranking of the pages?

Comment: what do you mean by "without losing Ranking of the pages", page ranking in Google?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

from "Redirecting to a different domain" in [Redirecting a Web Folder Directory to another Directory in htaccess](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/redirecting-a-web-folder-directory-to-another-in-htaccess/)

Comment: Must say, that is a very bizarre way of redirecting `olddomain.com` to `newdomain.com`!? But crucially, this would result in a redirect loop if `olddomain.com` and `newdomain.com` point to the same place (which would be the only reason for the `RewriteCond` directive in the first place). This answer also ignores the fact that only URLs within a particular folder should be redirected - not _everything_.

Answer (score 0):

In the `olddomain.com/subfolder/.htaccess` file you just need a single mod_alias `Redirect` directive to redirect all files to `newdomain.com/subfolder/<file>`:

```
Redirect 302 /subfolder http://www.newdomain.com/subfolder
```

Change the 302 (temporary) to 301 (permanent) only when you are sure it's working OK. (301s are cached hard by the browser, so can make testing problematic.)

However, if `olddomain.com` and `newdomain.com` point to the same place then you will need to use mod_rewrite and include a *condition* that specifically checks for the *host* being  requested, otherwise you'll get a redirect loop. For example, in the same `olddomain.com/subfolder/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

This redirects any request for `olddomain.com/subfolder/<anything>` to `http://www.newdomain.com/subfolder/<anything>`.

Again, change 302 to 301 when you are sure it's working OK.